# What is the most efficient way to check if coordinate didn't change for 10 minutes (c# or mssql) from a list of coords

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a list of GPS coordinates (lat,lon) with a timestamp that I got from GPS logger.
I want to find the first points that didn't change in a buffer of 100 meter for 10 minutes.
What will be the most efficient way to do this (I can do it in c# or in mssql) ?

for example , I drove my bike 20 k"m , stopped for half an hour (logger keep recording data every 10 seconds) and than continue to drive. I want to identify the first time I stayed in place in area of 100 meter (because logger isn't accurate) for atleast 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumes your data is a geography or is a geometry in a projection using meters

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [mylayer] l1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [mylayer] l2 WHERE l1.[my geom column].STBuffer(100).STIntersects(l2.[my geom column]) = 0 
    AND l2.[mytime] > l1.[mytime] 
    AND DateDiff(second, l1.[mytime], l2.[mytime]) <= 600)
ORDER BY l1.[mytime]
```

also try substituting

```
l1.[my geom column].STDistance(l2.[my geom column]) > 100
```

for

```
l1.[my geom column].STBuffer(100).STIntersects(l2.[my geom column]) = 0
```

and comparing performance.

For other projected geometry, replace 100 with equivalent distance in projection units.

Geometry in degrees will not work well since degrees of lat are not the same distance apart as lon.

Comment: Hi Russel , my geometry using SRID 0 which isn't meters (I've tested and STDIstance brings back weird result like 0.011 when I'm 100+ meters away) and also what about the time issue ? I need to stay in that buffer for 10minutes atleast.

Comment: The time buffer is what the DateDiff is for.  The query wants records for which there is no record more than 100 meters away and less than ten minutes older (I use 600 seconds because DateDiff returns integers).

Comment: edited DateDiff(sec to DateDiff(second,

Comment: If your geometry SRID is 0 then you don't know the projection.  But if you get back 0.011 for 100+ meters then it's in degrees.  In that case any distance you define will describe an ellipse rather than a circle.  You could convert the data to geography for better accuracy.

Comment: So you recommend me to create another column in the table called geography , set its SRID to 4326 and do the same query on that column (without changes) ?

Comment: Yes... do you need a snippet for geom to geog or have you got that under control?

Comment: I think I need to use Geog::STGeomFromText and set SRID to 4326. I'll test it and report back to you.

Comment: Hi Russel - Code didn't work. It gave me as result the entire table as is.

Comment: Very weird.  If you omit the conversion to geography and use a buffer distance like 0.001 does that still happen?  Also, to review the data and get the whole table I assume you omitted the "TOP 1"?  That's a valid check, but can you post the query as you ran it?

Comment: What do you mean posting the query ? Its identical to the one you did but with the real table names.

Comment: It can't be.  "TOP 1" would have returned only a single row, even if it wasn't the right one.